# how to make sure js is enabled before executing php function

Tags: ajax, javascript

I have a function that is in my post template and i need to make sure before executing the function that javascript is enabled. i have found a way using a cookie but it need to refresh the page twice to get accurate results and i think it is a bad practice for search engines too.
PS: i can't get the function code because its encrypted in ioncube i just have the right to call it.
Maybe if there is a way to call via ajax but i have no idea how to use ajax especially i don't have access to the functions code.

Comment: What does the PHP do? You're right, you can't tell in PHP whether the browser has working JavaScript or not, and making an AJAX call sounds sensible to me. (Although I've no idea if that's a good idea for search engines or not - do you expect the search engines to index the output of this function?)

Comment: no there is no need to index the outout of the function but the rest of the page can be indexed so would rather avoid refreshing the page